# SQL выбрать записи, в которых поле model состоит только из цифр или только из латинских букв

Tags: sql, like

Есть вариант покороче чем такое?

```
select model, type
from Product
where model like '[0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
or model like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
```

Comment: А какой диалекте SQL идет речь? Ответ может отличаться для разных диалектов

Comment: Укажите используемую DBMS. И, желательно, версию...

Comment: Тренируюсь на этом сайте: http://www.sql-ex.ru Насчет синтаксиса там написано: "В настоящее время на рейтинговых этапах мы используем Microsoft SQL Server 2017, а на обучающем этапе - дополнительно MariaDB-10.2.13 (совместима с MySQL 8), PostgreSQL 10.3 и Oracle Database 11g. Поэтому пользователю нужно придерживаться синтаксиса данных реализаций при написании своих запросов. "

Comment: http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php?LN=35 - ссылка на эту задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
SELECT model, type 
FROM product 
WHERE model NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' OR model NOT LIKE '%[^a-z]%'
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Для MySQL подойдет вариант:

```
select model, type
from Product
where (model regexp '^[0-9]*$') or model (model regexp '^[a-zA-Z]*$')
```

P.S. Я не сильно большой любитель/знаток регулярки - надеюсь коллеги поправят меня

Comment: Ругается: "Incorrect syntax near 'regexp'"

Comment: ну все правильно, у вас диалект, который не поддерживает регулярку (regexp)

Comment: Регулярки можно в одну объединить, наверное? И ещё один `model`, вероятно, лишний.

Comment: Да, конечно, можно, но я не спец в регулярных и вообще их не люблю - в ответе артикулировано